# File transfer from basespace to aws S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use the Illumina Basespace service to do high throughput sequencing secondary analyzes. This service uses AWS servers and therefore all files are stored on s3.
I would like to transfer the files (results of analyzes) from basespace to my own aws s3 account. I would like to know what would be the best strategy to make things go quickly knowing that in the end we can summarize it as a copy of files from an s3 bucket belonging to Illumina to an s3 bucket belonging to me.
The solutions I'm thinking of:

- use the CLI basespace tool to copy the files to our on premise servers then transfer them back to aws
- use this tool from an ec2 instance.
- use the illumina API to get a pre-signed download url (but then how can I use this url to download the file directly into my s3 bucket?).
  If I use an ec2 instance, what kind of instance do you recommend to have enough resources without having too much (and therefore spending money for nothing)?

Thanks in advance,

Quentin

Comment: so long as you have the credentials stored in your config files, you should be able to do `aws s3 cp bucket1/file1 bucket2/file1` where `bucket1/file1` is on basespace, and `bucket2` is your destination of choice.